# django Google-Oauth authentication error

Tags: python, django, oauth

when I have tried to authenticate with google Oauth2 i get this error

403 Client Error: 
Forbidden for url: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=ya29.UQK5LwsbfbnBTGBXmxeByXVP2SbBuCLIM2KxQlMRBbJYrKJANu0cWXWP4YbWjMQXQUjw&alt=json

my redirect uri is

http://localhost:8000/complete/google-oauth2/

Comment: Thats not enough info. Have a look at https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples/django_sample

Comment: If you visit the URL you'll probably see a JSON output containing the error message "Access Not Configured. The API (Google+ API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration." ... it seems that Google currently forces you to have the plus.me scope whether you request it or not, unless you use an older deprecated API.

Answer (score 13):

Enable the Google+ API in [Google Api Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library).

[image: Console developer - APIs de Google]